# Are Javascript for loops faster than while loops when dealing with DB transactions?

Tags: javascript, stored-procedures, transactions

I know that the discussion of whether while loops and for loops are faster is very popular, but I haven't seen any with this particular question.

I am currently developing stored procedures in Snowflake. These SPs use Javascript to handle the logic.
I have the need to create some loops to run several (potentially thousands) SQL queries so I was wondering which could be the best approach for performance and safety.

I am worried about using while loops because it seems to me that it would be slower if the condition to evaluate was dependent on the result of a transaction, because the JS thread would need to stop to wait for the Snowflake query to return data in order to evaluate it again, whereas a normal for loop would just increment/decrement the counter and evaluate from inside the JS thread without needing to wait for a new set of results.

Which also leads me to a new questions: If this is true, would it mean that a while loop is safer since the for loop has the chance of becoming losing sync (in regards to the results obtained from Snowflake)?

I am not saying that this is the way things happen, rather, I'm just trying to confirm if this is actually how it goes or if I'm wrong. As I said I could not find many related resources to this.

Comment: *whereas a normal for loop would just increment/decrement the counter and evaluate from inside the JS thread without needing to wait for a new set of results.* ...No? It depends on what sort of stuff is done inside the loop body. Both a `for` and a `while` loop could have blocking logic, or both of them could have non-blocking logic, or one but not the other. `while` vs `for` doesn't really have anything to do with it.

Comment: I meant it more in a sense of when the time to evaluate whether the loop should do another iteration or not. Like if I create a for loop that should iterate until `i` is no longer greater than a given constant number, it's my impression that Javascript would not need to wait for a response from the DB to keep running the loop. Whereas with a while loop that runs if a certain query is still returning results would probably need to wait to get all the responses before being able to run another iteration.

Comment: Whether you use a `for` loop or a `while` loop for that will not affect whether the loop body is blocking or non-blocking. *Whereas with a while loop that runs if a certain query is still returning results would probably need to wait to get all the responses before being able to run another iteration* Only if you deliberately `await`, but if you `await` in a `for` loop as well, it'll work the same

Comment: So the for loop is still blocked until it gets results from the transaction?